# Angular 2 async custom validator

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to implement async custom validation and i have the validation class as below

```
export class CustomValidators{
_auth_service;
constructor(auth_service:AuthService){
    this._auth_service = auth_service;
}

usernameTaken(control: Control) {
    console.log(this._auth_service);
    let q = new Promise<ValidationResult>((resolve, reject) => {
    this._auth_service.emailtaken('email='+control.value).subscribe(data=>{
            var result = data.json().result;
            console.log(result);
            if(result===true){
                resolve({"usernameTaken": data});
            }else{
                resolve(null);
            }
        });
});
return q;
}

}
```

And in my component

```
this.customValidators = new CustomValidators(this._auth_service);
```

The i add it to form control like so

```
this.emailControl = new Control('',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(ConfigService.EMAIL_REGEX)]),this.customValidators.usernameTaken);
```

You can see that i am trying to inject a service in my validator. And then to use the validator function in my component i had to create an object of the validator and use it's method. I have debugged to see that the `this._auth_service` property appear `undefined` in my validator method. It seems to be populated fine in my validator constructor.

I do not want to use the validator as directive which i understand makes injecting service easy.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does `this._auth_service` have a value in the constructor?

Comment: It does. But in the validator method it shows as `undefined`

Comment: It is `undefined` because `this` is not an instance of `CustomValidators`.

Comment: @dfsq So before using `bind()`, my validator was being called statically and was understandably out of context, and using `bind` makes the function being called as method of validator class?

Comment: Sort of. This is the same if you would do this: `var user = {name: 'Thomas', getName: function() { return this.name }}; var getName = user.getName; getName()`. Method is detauched from the base object, context lost. However, `var getName = user.getName.bind(user)` is bound to context and always execute properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are losing a context. You should bind validator method to validator instance object explicitly:

```
this.emailControl = new Control('', Validators.compose([
  Validators.required, 
  Validators.pattern(ConfigService.EMAIL_REGEX)
 ]), this.customValidators.usernameTaken.bind(this.customValidators));
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what `.bind()` does in this case?

Comment: [it should be noted](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html) (since the question is tagged TS)

Comment: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function that will invoke `this.customValidators.usernameTaken` with proper context. It is important because `this.customValidators.usernameTaken` is just a reference to a validator method which will have dynamic context, meaning that `this` inside of it depends on how this method is called, but `this` will not longer be `this.customValidators`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @drewmoore Bind is not harmful, it is very useful and powerful method for context execution control. Of course one should use it wisely, but the fact that it returns `any` is not always a problem (like in this case it's not at all). At the same time, using arrow function for what should be done with bind, looks hacky and weird. But it is possible of course too: `() => this.customValidators.usernameTaken()`.

Comment: @dfsq - agreed completely, I didn't mean to suggest you were falling into any pitfalls here, I just wanted to make sure OP was aware they exist before adding `bind()` to their general-case toolbelt. +1